# Green bean storage

Tags: beans, storage

I'd like to get into selling green bean to roasters and I'm looking for information on storing coffee at a very small commercial level (50-100 bags). Without anyone to tap directly in my network, I'm looking for information that will help me move this idea along.

How much space is need for 100 bags?

What's the shelf life of bags of green beans?

How do I inspect beans once they arrive?

And any other information related to green beans storage and transport is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That's too many questions at once... Could you break that down to single questions, with proper focus. And also perhaps share a bit what you have done on your side to answer the questions (an expectation on SE).

Comment: IMO instead of closing this question, it should have been edited to ask only about how to store green coffee beans for a longer period (up to a year). I think its an important question, which I haven't been able to find an answer yet.

Comment: question is closed so I can't really answer it properly,but this [article][1] covers most of the points in your question. 

[1]http://legacy.sweetmarias.com/library/node/9155